# how to get the height of a user's device in html

Tags: html, css, height, device, viewport

How can I find the height of a user's device to optimize an element's height?

The following is my css

```
section.sr {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background-image:  url(../images/simulation-1-waterfall.jpg);
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 25px 35px 30px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a viewport height and width units: `vh` and `vw`, thus `100vh` is equal 100% of viewport height.

The solution is:

```
section.sr {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background-image:  url(../images/simulation-1-waterfall.jpg);
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 25px 35px 30px;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
section.sr {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background-image:  url(../images/simulation-1-waterfall.jpg);
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 25px 35px 30px;
    height: screen.heightpx;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this in the head of your html:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height, initial-scale=1">
```

This will make `height: 100%;` be 100% of the device.

So if the device is 320px, `height: 100%;` will be 320px 
and `height: 50%;` would be 160px;

---

Keep in mind if you have a device with 320px with a `<div>` that is set to `height: 50%;` and then an `<img>` within that `<div>`, this nested image tag will only have a height of 160px if it is set to `height: 100%;`. Because it inherits from its parent.